# The new servicestack client for Xcode 7 and swift 2.0 can't successfully compile code it generates?

Tags: swift, servicestack, xcode7

Basically we have met a lot of problems to even compile the code that works in Xcode 6.4

Our entire stack of APIs are written with servicestack but we didn't use many of them with servicestack swift client. Only a few of them, so many DTOs are not usable even in xcode 6.4 But it compiles fine and we get to use those APIs that we specifically modified to accomandate servicestack swift client.

And now after a few days we have tested the latest servicestack swift client for XCode 7. And immediately there are 500+ error. Mostly can be categoried into 2-3 error types.

- Type 'xxxxxx' does not conform to protocol 'Has Metadata' (because we don't have ireturn?)
- Type alias 'Return' must be declared public because it matches a requirement in public protocol 'IReturn' (This one we do have a return type set, and this should be the one that we really care about and want to be able to call)
- Static member 'toJson' cannot be used on instance of type 'xxxxx'
- Static member 'fromObject' cannot be used on instance of type 'xxxxx'

Also, can we just ignore everything else and ask the plugin to include only 3 APIs that we really care about? I saw there is a commented area at the top called //IncludeTypes: 
//ExcludeTypes: 
Can we just use that? IF we can, how should we?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the [v4.0.46 Release Notes on Swift 2.0 Support](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/docs/2015/release-notes.md#swift-20-support).

The just released Xcode 7 only comes with **Swift 2.0** which is a breaking language change that was only first added in ServiceStack **v4.0.46**. So if you want to use Xcode 7 you need to upgrade to v4.0.46.

You'll also need to download the latest [ServiceStack Xcode 7 Plugin](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Swift/raw/master/dist/ServiceStackXcode.dmg).

If you only want to include a few types you can use [IncludeTypes](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Swift-Add-ServiceStack-Reference#includetypes).

Comment: @shawhu Please edit your question to include the C# DTO and generate Swift DTO.

Comment: Ah, got you. We should upgrade servicestack, our server side library... Thanks!

Comment: I'll change my question but don't know what do you mean, you want me to change my question title to something else? Or add some extra tags?

Comment: @shawhu If it's still a problem or in future when you have an issue like this, in addition to the compiler errors, please also include the C# class that's causing the issue along with the Swift class that gets generated. Basically we'll need this in order to be able to reproduce the error you have.

Comment: Got it, will do. Actually all the problems are caused by a outdated servicestack DLL which after we have updated it, everything checks out. Thanks! And I'll include details about the DTOs and codes next time. I did it last time but this time somehow I figured it has to be a easy fix and shouldn't be a problem in the code itself so I haven't includes detailed code